# Function assigned to a variable in C

Tags: c

I did a test :

test1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
   getchar();
}
```

test2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
   int c;
   c = getchar();
}
```

Both test1.c and test2.c produce the same result which wait for the user to type something.

My questions :

1. In test2.c, I only assign a function of getchar() into variable 'c', and I never invoke/call the function , so why does it get invoked? The reason why I said it gets invoked is because when I run it, it produces the same result as test1.c
2. I thought a function only gets invoked when we invoke/call it, just like in test1.c , I invoke the function of getchar(). But in test2.c , I never invoke the function, I only assign the getchar() function to variable 'c'

Comment: `getchar()` is a function call expression. Of course you call the function.

Comment: You've been misled by the term "function". getchar is an IO operation, not a function, and you are calling it. If it was a pure function the compiler could optimise it away to nothing (in both cases in fact since you never output the result),

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean: Of course `getchar` is a function! What is an "IO operation"? Can you provide a reference to the standard defining this term?

Comment: @Olaf, I agree with you on this

Comment: The C standard misuses the term "function" which has an accepted meaning, when it means "subroutine". A function is a mapping of an input set (of bits) to an output set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In test2.c, I only assign a function of `getchar()` into variable `c`, and I never invoke/call the function, so why does it get invoked?

C makes a difference between a function name, which is `getchar` with no parentheses, and a function invocation expression, which is `getchar()` with parentheses. Your code does not assign a function to a variable; it assigns the result produced by function invocation to variable `c`.

> I thought a function only gets invoked when we invoke/call it, just like in `test1.c`

The difference between the two invocations, in test1.c vs. test2.c, is that test1.c invokes the function using a *statement*, while test2.c invokes the function using an *expression*. Both programs do invoke a function, though.

Answer (score 1):

The opening and closing parenthesis after the name `getchar` in C means to call the function associated with the name `getchar`. Therefore, in both code snippets you are actually calling the function.

If you wanted to "assign" the function to a variable `c`, it would look like this:

```
int (*c)() = &getchar;
```

What you're really doing above is taking the address of `getchar` and assigning it to the function pointer `c`.

Comment: Note: C is not a scripting language.